# Can I determine number of byte transfer using DMA subsystem in linux?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, i2c, dma

I have a code that write data to a I2C-EEPROM. The i2c-driver is config to use DMA. But is there anyway I can check that data is transfered by i2c using DMA from my program in user-space?

Thanks!

Comment: Roughly you may check the interrupt counter of DMA controller (if it's a separate device). Otherwise it's hardly to achieve. And usually i2c buses (their drivers) are not using DMA at all.

Comment: Oh! good suggestion. You are right, I can check it there. Many thanks!